# Reusing Kinect v1 code with Kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect

Can the code for an application designed for Kinect v1 (released for Xbox 360) be used for Kinect v2 (released for xbox one)?.

I understand that SDKs differ greatly.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df45c604-ed3f-471e-bb90-772393186fb0/does-kinect-for-windows-v2-works-with-kinect-for-windows-sdk-18?forum=kinectsdk)

> In short, **No**.
>
> Each SDK is tied to the specific hardware device; Kinect for Windows
>   v1 device - Kinect for Windows SDK v1.x Kinect for Windows v2 device -
>   Kinect for Windows SDK v2.x
>
> The version 2 SDK is a new compatibility band for Kinect for Windows.
>   In addition to acquiring a v2 sensor, developers will need to port
>   their application to the v2 SDK. In most cases, we have seen these
>   ports go smoothly for developers. The v2 API is an evolution of the
>   Managed API for Kinect for Windows, so it is easy to port the vast
>   majority of applications.

Answer (score 0):

No, never.

You have answer in your question. Both SDKs differ so much. Implementation of your code using both SDKs is completely different. You can try out that by trying kinect v1 projects with a kinect v2.

My advice would be to start coding from beginning. There are great [online support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn799271.aspx) for Kinects.

Answer (score 0):

No Never;
because main difference is between  Skeleton Class in Kinect V1 and Body Class in kinect V2